# How do I set DNS round-robin traffic percentage with bind9?

Tags: dns, bind, load-balancer

`bind9` allows you to configure DNS round-robin to multiple different IPs like:

```
server A 10.10.10.1
server A 10.10.10.2
```

And it'll return 50%/50% approximate.

However, I need it to return, for example, 1/4 of the queries with 10.10.10.1 and 3/4 with 10.10.10.2. I tried to do something like that but this does not work:

```
server A 10.10.10.1
server A 10.10.10.2
server A 10.10.10.2
server A 10.10.10.2
```

...as it returns 50%/50% of each IP.

How can I achieve that?

I use Debian 10 and Bind 9.11.5

Comment: I believe bind9 does not have this functionality natively, but you may be able to cheat this system slightly through a bit of a hack. Can you give 10.10.10.2 two additional virtual IPs, configure that server to listen on them, and then add the virtual IPs to your bind config?

Comment: In Round Robin Load Balancing, you can allows site administrators to assign weights to each server based on criteria like traffic-handling capacity. please refer to https://avinetworks.com/glossary/round-robin-load-balancing/